# Solidity function implementing `public onlyOwner` cannot be called even by the owner

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ether

I am following along the documentation here: https://docs.alchemyapi.io/alchemy/tutorials/how-to-create-an-nft/how-to-mint-a-nft. And have a smart contract of form:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

  contract NFTA is ERC721, Ownable {

     using Counters for Counters.Counter;
     Counters.Counter public _tokenIds;
     mapping (uint256 => string) public _tokenURIs;
     mapping(string => uint8) public hashes;

     constructor() public ERC721("NFTA", "NFT") {}

     function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
          public onlyOwner
          returns (uint256)
      {
          _tokenIds.increment();

          uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
          _mint(recipient, newItemId);
          _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

          return newItemId;
     }

     /**
      * @dev Sets `_tokenURI` as the tokenURI of `tokenId`.
      *
      * Requirements:
      *
      * - `tokenId` must exist.
      */
     function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) internal virtual {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721URIStorage: URI set of nonexistent token");
        _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
     }    

  }
```

When I attempt to estimate the gas cost of `minting` with this:

```
    const MY_PUBLIC_KEY  = '..'
    const MY_PRIVATE_KEY = '..'

    const ALCHEMY = {
        http: '',
        websocket:'',
    }

    const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");
    const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(ALCHEMY.http);

    const NFTA = require("../artifacts/contracts/OpenSea.sol/NFTA.json");
    const address_a   = '0x...';
    const nft_A = new web3.eth.Contract(NFTA.abi, address_a);


    async function mint({ tokenURI, run }){

        const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(MY_PUBLIC_KEY, 'latest'); 
        const fn  = nft_A.methods.mintNFT(MY_PUBLIC_KEY, '')

        console.log( 'fn: ', fn.estimateGas() )
    }

    mint({ tokenURI: '', run: true })
```

I receive error:

```
(node:29262) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: execution reverted: Ownable: caller is not the owner
```

Presumably because `mintNFT` is `public onlyOwner`. However, when I check Etherscan, the `From` field is the same as `MY_PUBLIC_KEY`, and I'm not sure what else can be done to sign the transaction as from `MY_PUBLIC_KEY`. The easy way to solve this is to remove the `onlyOwner` from `function mintNFT`, and everything runs as expected. But suppose we want to keep `onlyOwner`, how would I sign the transaction beyond what is already written above.

Note I'm using `hardHat` to compile the contracts and deploying them. That is:
npx hardhat compile
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js

=============================================

addendum

The exact code given by alchemy to deploy the mint is:

```
async function mintNFT(tokenURI) {
  const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY, 'latest'); //get latest nonce

  //the transaction
  const tx = {
    'from': PUBLIC_KEY,
    'to': contractAddress,
    'nonce': nonce,
    'gas': 500000,
    'data': nftContract.methods.mintNFT(PUBLIC_KEY, tokenURI).encodeABI()
  };
```

Note in the transaction the `from` field is `PUBLIC_KEY`, the same `PUBLIC_KEY` that deployed the contract, and in this case the `nftContract` has `public onlyOwner` specified. This is exactly what I have done. So conceptually who owns this NFT code? On etherscan is it the `to` address ( the contract address ), or the `from` address, which is my public key, the address that deployed the contract, and the one that is calling mint, which is now failing with caller is not the owner error. [image]

Search the internet, I see others have encountered this problem here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94114/erc721-testing-transferfrom, for `Truffle` you can specify the caller with extra field:

```
 await nft.transferFrom(accounts[0], accounts[1], 1, { from: accounts[1] })
```

Extra parameters is not an option here because I'm using hardhat.

Comment: I guess your need to pass the test account sender address when you call `methods.mintNFT`.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa how would i do that? And is the test account sender address the same as my metamask wallet public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, the contract does not initialize the way I deploy it. So you have to initialize it after deployment.

Answer (score 6):

OpenZeppelin's [Ownable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L28) defines the default `owner` value as the contract deployer. You can later change it by calling `transferOwnership()` or renounce the owner (i.e. set to `0x0`) by calling `renounceOwnership()`.

**The `onlyOwner` modifier reverts the transaction if it's not sent by the current `owner`.** ([see the code](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L43))

So you need to call the `mintNFT()` function from the same address that deployed the contract, because that's the current `owner`. Or you can change the `owner` first by calling `transferOwnership()` (from the current `owner` address).

Removing the `onlyOwner` modifier from the `mintNFT()` function would allow **anyone** to call the function.

Comment: this is the question, I only have one public key going around, shouldn't that be the address that deployed the contract?

Comment: And when I call `transferOwnership` I'm getting the same error: ` Error: Returned error: execution reverted: Ownable: caller is not the owner`, stating that I'm not calling the fn from the address that deployed it. But again I only have one wallet and one pk, so Im not sure what else i can do. Mikko above suggest I call `mintNFT` and presumably `transferOwner` using test account sender address, what is the syntax here? And conceptually on Etherscan I see a `to` and `from` field for the contract, is the owner the `to` field or the `from` field?

Comment: @xiaolingxiao (1/2) From your screenshot, I can see that the contract [0xa26c...](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xa26ca1c799b87bdcc9ca3440ebf4b42fc4725b57) was deployed by address `0xd2590...`, effectively making this address the `owner`. And that this address [was able](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb27b831df503cc427e3fd76ea76920dc7bdcefeafd550a3c79bcb529e657c6b4) to execute the `mintNFT()` function.

Comment: (2/2) It seems like the value of your `MY_PUBLIC_KEY` is other than `0xd2590...` - which gets the tx reverted, only the `owner` can execute it. Also pay attention to the value of `MY_PUBLIC_KEY` which might be different from the `PUBLIC_KEY` in your second snippet. But I'm not able to verify it, because your question doesn't show the values.

Comment: The reason the contract was able to mint was because I removed the onlyOwner bit in the one that i deployed, i was trying to verify that it runs w/o the ownership constraint. And yeah I only have one pk that's 0xd2590.... The second snippet is a direct past from the docs, in my code PUBLIC_KEY is MY_PUBLIC_KEY. This is why it's so infuriatingly fraustrating, I only have one pk private key pair, and that's what I use to deploy the contract and sign transactions. @PetrHejda

Comment: Just to confirm, I redployed with `onlyOwner` set here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xea93afe6195cc201ca38157504b3852736a1b33a7644515ec230669a7c4dca96, and mintNFT fails with: `Error: Returned error: execution reverted: Ownable: caller is not the owner` as expected

Comment: "I removed the onlyOwner", I didn't notice that - my bad... But right now, I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone will be able to help you better.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the concept of `onlyOwner`, if your public key is public, then can't anyone call the fn with your pk provided they have it? it doesn't exactly make `onlyOwner` secure.

Comment: They would have to sign the transaction with the private key that pairs with the `owner` public key.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this for anyone else who stumbles across the issue while using the Alchemy tutorial:

In the tutorial, it says to init the contract in your mint method like this:

```
const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/MyNFT.sol/MyNFT.json");
const contractAddress = "0x81c587EB0fE773404c42c1d2666b5f557C470eED";
const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contractAddress);
```

However, if you attempt to call estimateGas() or encodeABI() it will fail with the onlyOwner error.

The solution is to change the third line to:

```
const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contractAddress, {
    from: PUBLIC_KEY
});
```

This will set a default value of "From" so that when you call estimateGas() on a mint function marked onlyOwner, it will be able to use that from field to see that its the owner calling the estimateGas.

Took forever to figure this out.

Comment: Thank you so much! You can also add `from: PUBLIC_KEY` directly to the data passed into `estimateGas()`: `const estimatedGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({ from: PUBLIC_KEY, to: contractAddress, ...})`.